# Conversion of SVG to PNG works on chrome but not on firefox

Tags: javascript, svg, png

I'm trying to convert SVG to PNG which works fine on chrome but on firefox the image url shows blank any idea

```
function svgToPng(svg, callback) {
  const url = getSvgUrl(svg);
  svgUrlToPng(url, (imgData) => {
    callback(imgData);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  });
}
function getSvgUrl(svg) {
  return URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([svg], { type: "image/svg+xml" }));
}
function svgUrlToPng(svgUrl, callback) {
  const svgImage = document.createElement("img");
  document.body.appendChild(svgImage);

  svgImage.onload = function () {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = svgImage.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = svgImage.clientHeight;

    const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvasCtx.drawImage(svgImage, 0, 0);
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    callback(imgData);
    document.body.removeChild(svgImage);
  };
  svgImage.src = svgUrl;
}
```

Tried other methods but did not work

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: No, so the callback returns a base64 url which when i check on the browser it's blank but on chrome it works fine

Comment: I had the same issue, you have to set `width` and `height` attributes on `svg` element